# jQuery .append() called from within for loop. (Closure Issue?)

Tags: jquery, closures, append

I have a hunch this may be related to closures (or, a lack thereof).

Here's the jQuery I'm using:

```
function appendToWrapper(wrapper, newNode, loop, version){
  newNode
     .text(loop+version);
  wrapper
    .append(newNode); 
}

var template = $("<div></div>");

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
   appendToWrapper($('#wrapper'), template, i, 'a');
   appendToWrapper($('#wrapper'), template, i, 'b');
}
```

What I want to produce is output that looks like this:

```
0a
0b
1a
1b
2a
...
9b
```

But this is what I end up with;

```
9b
```

I think this is a closure issue, right? Any hints on the direction to go in to fix this? (I'm still trying to wrap my head around closures).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a div for each iteration.
Change you code to as follows:

```
function appendToWrapper(wrapper, newNode, loop, version){
  newNode
     .text(loop+version);
  wrapper
    .append(newNode); 
}

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
   var template = $("<div></div>");
   appendToWrapper($('#wrapper'), template, i, 'a');
   appendToWrapper($('#wrapper'), template, i, 'b');
}
```

Working example @: http://jsfiddle.net/eMxBV/

Comment: 'doh! That was it! Thank you!

Comment: This is a trivial point and DA would have already fixed it. But, to get the exact same output as required by DA the code should be: 

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         var template = $("<div></div>");
         appendToWrapper($('#wrapper'), template, i, 'a');
         template = $("<div></div>");
         appendToWrapper($('#wrapper'), template, i, 'b');
    } 

i.e. reinitialize template for 'b' again.