# jQuery prepend() doing nothing

Tags: jquery, html

I have no errors that I can see on my console, yet my loop doesn't seem to be inserting anything into my div. You'll see the prepend in the first FOR loop.

http://jordan.rave5.com/tmpstuff/

**jQuery**

```
// Start Slides
$.get('http://jordan.rave5.com/tmpstuff/slides.txt', function (data) {
    var lineArray = data.split('\n'),
        slideList = [],
        count = lineArray.length;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var line = lineArray[i].split('{|}');
        slideList[i] = [],
        slideList[i]['id'] = line[0],
        slideList[i]['url'] = line[1];
        $('#header-image-border').prepend('<img id="' + line[0] + '" class="header-image-size" src="' + line[1] + '" alt="The Tiger Spot" />');
    }
});
$('#hi1').fadeTo(2000, 1.0, function () {
    var slide = 0,
        slideShow = setInterval(function () {
            var nextSlide = slide + 1;
            if (nextSlide > count - 1) {
                nextSlide = 0;
            }
            $(slideList[slide]['id']).fadeTo(600, 0);
            $(slideList[nextSlide]['id']).fadeTo(2300, 1.0);
            slide++;
            if (slide > count - 1) {
                slide = 0;
            }
        }, 20000);
    // End Slides
```

**slides.txt**

```
#hi1{|}slides/head1.jpg
#hi2{|}slides/head2.jpg
#hi3{|}slides/head3.jpg
#hi4{|}slides/head4.jpg
#hi5{|}slides/head5.jpg
```

Comment: Are you sure that it gets called?

Comment: You mean it prepends ones time? because you only have one for loop in your posted code.?

Comment: the prepend is working fine, you can inspect the element using browser's development toolbar, the img nodes are added to it

Comment: it is a problem with display properties of the element

Comment: Weird. I didn't change anything but the slider code and it killed the entire layout? Lol I literally just removed the img tags from the HTML and added them to the slides.txt then made the loop to go through it and assign the data in arrays

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new div for each prepend. Create a template for your div that you can clone each cycle.

[jQuery .append() called from within for loop. (Closure Issue?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190093/jquery-append-called-from-within-for-loop-closure-issue)

Comment: The code writes fine, it appears it somehow has cause the entire JS script to break.I fear it may be timing with the fades?

Comment: Well i know jquery does not usually do well when taking action on elements not yet on the page, that is why I thought creating a div template would solve this.

Comment: Maybe have dummy images and replace the soureces since that's what I'm working with? Since the opacity is set to 0 it's not like they will be in the way, and the script will only fade in what it uses.

Comment: So I changed sources, the sources change fine, however the slider seems to be fading out to "head1.jpg" which it initially was on page load. Is this some sort of slider that would be on window load and not document ready?

Comment: I think it appears that way because your for loop takes longer now.

Comment: I would try to load a hidden image or set a time out to offset this?

Answer (score 0):

The `prepend()` works, all your images have `opacity:0` set on them which is why they don't appear on the page.

Comment: They are suppose to. The slider controls that as you see below that prepend code. The problem is, since using the prepend to add the images dynamically it broke the layout I guess.